# Implementing Interesting Encoding Method in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

### Preface

I am working on implementing the Genetic Algorithm for the Traveling Salesman problem. I am making some base line assumption such as you can travel to any city from any city. While this is for an assignment, I have extended this to a personal project as the deadline is past and I have chosen to use Lisp which definitely was not required. The point of encoding my data in this way listed below is to easily perform cross-over later in the algorithm.

### Problem

Suppose you have a list of cities, given similar to the following

```lisp
(defvar *data* (list
               '(A 20 10)
               '(B 5  16)
               '(C 12 18)
               '(D x  y)
               '(E x  y)
               ...
```

I want to encode this data in a way similar to this:
[image: City encoding method]

and I for the life of me cannot figure out how to implement this in Lisp. If anyone has some insight, it would be much appreciated. If there is a better way to create my `*data*` set that would make this easier feel free to include it!

Comment: I don't understand - what is the `Index Table` for - is this kind of a dictionary? how does this fit together with the data given in `*data*`? And for what you need the `Next City and Index` and the `Indexlist` for what they are good and how they are connected to each other? You don't explain their relationships to each other ...

Comment: ah slowly I understand - given a route, you want to remove from the pool of remaining possible cities those which are visited ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I understood it. Here is the solution:

```
(defparameter *data* (list
                     '(A 20 10)
                     '(B 5 16)
                     '(C 12 18)
                     '(D x y)
                     '(E x y)))
```

For one step you need a function which looks up index position of the city in the city-list (`*data*`) and also removes its entry in the city-list and returns the updated city-list.

```
(defun choose-city (city-list city-name)
  "Return city-name with its index position
  and city-list with the chosen city removed, keeping the order."
  (let* ((cities (mapcar #'car city-list))
         (pos (position city-name cities)))
    (list city-name 
          pos 
          (append (subseq city-list 0 pos)
                  (subseq city-list (+ pos 1) (length city-list))))))

;; improved version by @Kaz - thanks! (lispier)
(defun choose-city (city-list city-name)
  (list city-name 
        (positiion city-name city-list :key #'car :test #'eql)
        (remove city-name city-list :key #'car :test #'eql)))
```

Then, you need a function which applies the previous function
over and over again while collecting the index positions and updates from step to step the `city-list` by removing the matched `current-city` in the `city-sequence`.
A typical pattern occuring in lisp for this is
to define the to-be-mutated variable as a local variable in a `let` expression and from the body of the `let`-expression to update the variable value using `setf` (setf-ing).

```
(defun choose-cities-subsequently (city-list city-sequence)
  "Return sequence of subsequent-index-positions of the cities
  given in city-sequence. After choosing a sequence, the city is
  removed from the city-list and its index position of the previous
  pool taken for record."
  (let ((index-positions '()) ; initiate collector variable
        (current-city-list city-list)) ; current state of city-list
    (loop for current-city in city-sequence
          do (progn
               ;; call `choose-city` and capture its results
               (destructuring-bind 
                 (name index new-city-list) ; capturing vars
                 ;; and in the following the function call:
                 (choose-city current-city-list current-city) 
                 ;; update collector variable and 
                 ;; current-city-list using the captured values
                 (setf index-positions (cons index index-positions))
                 (setf current-city-list new-city-list)))
          ;; if city-sequence processed in this way, 
          ;; return the collected index-positions.
          ;; remark: cons-ing during collecting and 
          ;; at the end nreverse-ing the result
          ;; when/while returning 
          ;; is a very typical lisp idiom 
          finally (return (nreverse index-positions)))))

;; improved version by @Kaz - thanks!
(defun choose-cities-subsequently (city-list city-sequence)
  (let ((index-positions '()) ; initiate collector variable
        (current-city-list city-list)) ; current state of city-list
    (loop for current-city in city-sequence
          collect (destructuring-bind 
              (name index new-city-list) 
              (choose-city current-city-list current-city) 
                    (setf current-city-list new-city-list)
                    index)
        into index-positions
      finally (return index-positions)))))
```

Now, if you run

```
(choose-cities-subsequently *data* '(A D E B C))
```

it returns correctly:

```
(0 2 2 0 0)
```

By defining more `let`-variables in the last function and
`setf`-fing to those in the `destructuring-bind` expression's body, and returning the final value in the final list,
you can collect more informations and make them visibile.

## Tried to simplify a little and recursive definition

```
(defparameter *data* (list
                     '(A 20 10)
                     '(B 5 16)
                     '(C 12 18)
                     '(D x y)
                     '(E x y)))

(defun choose-city (city-list city-name)
  (list (position city-name city-list :key #'car :test #'eql)
        (remove city-name city-list :key #'car :test #'eql)))
;; when city names are strings use `:test #'string=

(defun choose-cities-subsequently (city-list city-sequence)
  (let ((current-cities city-list))
    (loop for current-city in city-sequence
          for (idx updated-cities) = (choose-city current-cities current-city)
          collect (progn (setf current-cities updated-cities)
                         idx)
            into index-positions
          finally (return index-positions))))

(choose-cities-subsequently *cities* '(A D E B C))
;; (0 2 2 0 0)

;; a tail-call recursive version:
(defun choose-cities-subsequently (cities city-sequence 
                                   &key (acc-cities '()) 
                                        (acc-positions '())
                                        (pos-counter 0)
                                        (test #'eql))
    (cond ((or (null city-sequence) (null cities)) (nreverse acc-positions))
          ((funcall test (car city-sequence) (car cities))
           (choose-cities-subsequently (append (nreverse acc-cities) (cdr cities))
                                       (cdr city-sequence)
                                       :acc-cities '()
                                       :acc-positions (cons pos-counter acc-positions)
                                       :pos-counter 0
                                       :test test))
          (t (choose-cities-subsequently (cdr cities)
                                         city-sequence
                                         :acc-cities (cons (car cities) acc-cities)
                                         :acc-positions acc-positions
                                         :pos-counter (1+ pos-counter)
                                         :test test))))
```

Comment: Dude, nice! It took me a while to wrap my head around this, and it definitely helped in furthering my understanding of Lisp. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DenverEllis Welcome! May you be enlightened in your path - and the force be with you! xD

Comment: You can use `position` on the original list without `mapcar`-ing out the cities! `position` takes `:key` and `:test` arguments.  `(position city-name city-list :key #'car)`.

Comment: The `append` `subseq` manipulation can be replaced with `(remove city-name city-list :key #'car)`.

Comment: @Kaz thanks! I was suspecting that :key and :test arguments could be given, but was too lazy to check. Thanks!

Comment: `(setf index-positions (cons index index-positions))` does the same thing as `(push index index-positions)`.   But the whole push now and nreverse later idiom can be avoided if we're using `loop`, by  making use of `collect`, or `collect <expr> into <loop-var>`.